# Request failed with status code 403 - magiceden api with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Please help me, I'm so stuck on this problem: I'm making a request **magiceden.io API** with [Axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro) on Javascript and the request is not working (Request failed with status code 403).

My URL request: https://api-mainnet.magiceden.io/new_collections

My code:

```
axios.get("https://api-mainnet.magiceden.io/new_collections", {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
    },
}).then((res) => {
     console.log(res.data);
}).catch((err) => {
     console.log(err.message);
});
```

Comment: Status 403 means request is Forbidden. may be you miss to send api key or secret key in your request header.

Answer (score 0):

Status 403 means that the request is a forbidden access. It is probably because MagicEden now uses Cloudflare protection which restricts access. You can try changing your request headers which can bypass the cloudflare protection.